# How to do modal windows in ASP.NET MVC 3 + Telerik Window Control

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, telerik-window

As the title says, I am trying to put together a modal window using Telerik Window control (I guess the same applies for jQuery UI as well) and ASP.NET MVC 3.

A quick mock to help visualize the requirement:

[image: Mockup to get the idea across]

I have implemented a few solutions to this, but I am not sure if there is a better (more recommended way.)

Few questions that I have:

- The HTML for the form: Should I use the Telerik LoadContentFrom client API call to load the HTML from a URL?
- Should I render it in line in the containing page (somehow this doesn't look a good idea) by using a partial view?
- Whats the best way to re-init the input fields in the the modal popup when the user clicks it again the second time?

Comment: why tag it with `knockoutjs` ?